# using preg_replace in php to remove space in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following String `+ Example + Test + Test2` and using preg_replace I would like to get the following result `+Example +Test +Test2`

I have been trying to use the following code

```
preg_replace("/\s*([\+])\s*/", "$1", $string)
```

but this one is returning

```
+Example+Test+Test2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$output = str_replace('+ ', '+', $input);
```

or

```
$output = preg_replace('/\\+\\s+/', '+', $input);
```

Comment: What about multiple spaces before the +? I know the Q doesn't say it (but it implies it). Just being mischievous :)

Comment: $output = trim(preg_replace('/\s*+\s*/', ' +', $input));